# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDataRange' of null on trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I keep getting this error on a couple of my google scripts and have never had this problem until the past week.  I have not changed my scripts.

```
function importData2() {

var sourceSpreadsheetID = "source spreadsheet ID";
var sourceWorksheetName = "Lewis Ford of Dodge City - Flow";
var targetSpreadsheetID = "target spreadsheet ID";
var targetWorksheetName = "forddodgecity";

  var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetID);
  var thisWorksheet = thisSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceWorksheetName);
  var thisData = thisWorksheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var toSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheetID);
  var toWorksheet = toSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetWorksheetName);
  toWorksheet.clearContents();
  toWorksheet.getRange(1, 1, thisData.length, thisData[0].length).setValues(thisData); 
}
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDataRange' of null (line 10, file "Dodge City"). this is the other error when i try to push it manually.

Comment: Hi Lydia - well, obviously `thisWorksheet` holds a value of `null`. What's left is to determine what is causing it - maybe the sheet with name referenced by `sourceWorksheetName` got renamed or deleted. Btw, which trigger type are you talking about?

Comment: A timer trigger!  and I know the sheet is populated by the time the trigger is activated

Comment: Oh one of my employees renamed it! thank you for your help again :)

Comment: No problem - yep, one of the usual reasons with this error. Add a guard, something like `if ( thisWorksheet  === null ) { //do something - log, send a notification, etc }`

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

The sheet referenced by `sourceWorksheetName` got renamed causing `getSheetByName()` to return `null`

**Solutions**

There are a lot of ways to prevent this from happening, here are two most common ones - intrusive and non-intrusive:

---

*Forbid renaming of sheets*

Here is a rather complex catch-all solution that can persist across users. Should be installed as an [`onChange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onChange()) trigger to work. The first of the two functions is a utility to simplify creation and retrieval of properties.

Also note that you should run it at least once for it to take effect properly.

```
/**
 * @summary updates current spreadsheet structure
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Spreadsheet} spread 
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Properties.Properties} propStore 
 * @param {string} propName 
 * @returns {string}
 */
const updatePersistedStructure = (spread, propStore, propName) => {
    const info = {
        sheets: spread.getSheets().map(sheet => {
            return {
                id: sheet.getSheetId(),
                name: sheet.getSheetName()
            };
        })
    };

    const stringified = JSON.stringify(info);
    propStore.setProperty(propName, stringified);

    return stringified;
};

/**
 * 
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Events.SheetsOnChange} e 
 */
function stopSheetRenaming(e) {

    const { changeType } = e;

    if (changeType === "OTHER") {
        const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

        const propName = "structure";

        //get persisted structure or initialize it;
        const store = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
        let savedStructure = store.getProperty(propName) || updatePersistedStructure(ss, store, propName);

        const { sheets } = JSON.parse(savedStructure);
        const currentSheets = ss.getSheets();

        let renamedInfo = null, renamedSheet = null;

        const sheetRenamed = sheets.some((sheetInfo) => {
            const { id, name } = sheetInfo;

            const currentSheet = currentSheets.find(sheet => sheet.getSheetId() === id);
            const removed = currentSheet === undefined;

            if (removed) {
                return false; //we don't care about removed sheets;
            }

            const currentName = currentSheet.getSheetName();
            const isRenamed = currentName !== name;

            if (isRenamed) {
                renamedSheet = currentSheet;
                renamedInfo = Object.assign(sheetInfo, { newName: currentName });
            }

            return isRenamed;
        });

        if (sheetRenamed) {
            const { name, newName } = renamedInfo;

            renamedSheet.setName(name);

            const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
            ui.alert(`Sheet renaming is forbidden.\n\nTried to rename ${name} to ${newName}`);
        }

        updatePersistedStructure(ss, store, propName);
    }
}
```

---

*Reference the sheet by Id*

Another, less restrictive solution is to avoid referencing the sheet by what can be arbitrarily changed. Although for an unknown reason ATTOW there is no method that can directly return a sheet by its ID, you can get the desired sheet like this:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheets = ss.getSheets();

const id = "ID here";

const targetSheet = sheets.find(sheet => sheet.getSheetId() === id);
```

And to find a sheet Id to avoid hardcoding (the sample concerns the currently active sheet) you can use [`getSheetId()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetid) method:

```
const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
const id = sh.getSheetId();
```